# Headers are not displayed in some parts

Tags: header-footer

In fact, I have a problem in the headers. In chapter 1 and 2 there are no problems everything is fine but in the table of contents, list of figures and list of tables there are no headers and in the introduction part it's displayed chapter 0. List of figures which doesn't make sense. Here is the code:

```
\immediate\write18{makeindex \jobname.nlo -s nomencl.ist -o \jobname.nls}
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{$}l<{$}}
\newcolumntype{m}{>{\displaystyle}l}
\usepackage{cclicenses}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{titleps}
\newpagestyle{mystyle}{%
\headrule\sethead{\textsc \chaptername\ \thechapter. \textsc \chaptertitle}
{}{}
\setfoot{}{\thepage}{}\footrule}
\pagestyle{mystyle}
\usepackage[a4paper,right=20mm,left=25mm,top=20mm, bottom=20mm]{geometry}
\makeatletter
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{20pt}
\makeatother
\title {Tile of the report }
\titleformat{\paragraph}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
\doublespacing
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\chapter*{Publications}
\chapter*{acknowledegement}
I want...
\chapter*{table list}
\listoffigures
\renewcommand{\nomname}{abbreviation list}
\printnomenclature
\chapter*{Introduction }
\lipsum
\chapter{state of art}
\lipsum
\chapter{theory}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Without testing: `\chaptername\ \thechapter. \textsc \chaptertitle` should probably be `leftmark`?

Comment: I have used \headrule\sethead{\textsc \chaptername\ \thechapter. \textsc \chaptertitle

Comment: I saw that. That's why i suggested to use `\leftmark`. I didn't test your example, it is huge and does unnecessary stuff that has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: Where can I use \leftmark

Comment: Just look at my first comment (sorry, a `\ ` is missing there). Use  `A` instead of `B` (A and B being the highlithed things).

Comment: Yes but I don't see any difference it's always \chaptername\ \thechapter. \textsc \chaptertitle

Comment: @Johannes_B: The interest of `titlesec/titleps` is precisely to avoid the hassle of the marks system.

Comment: `\sethead{\leftmark}` removes the head from the introduction page. Why? It is a starred chapter. The artifact you are seeing is gone. I cannot reproduce what you are describing.

Comment: @Bernard Ah right, i remember why i don't use those packages.

Comment: And I didn't forget why I use them… :o)

Comment: So how can I include headers in introduction and list of figures,tables and table of contents ?

Comment: I think your question is two-fold. When a chapter starts, the header is empty by design (`plain`). You would need to renew this pagestyle.

Comment: I would like to have an example code if it's possible

Comment: Do you rely on package `titleps`? Or would an alternative package do? Personally i like [scrlayer-scrpage](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Customizing_Page_Headers_and_Footers#Customizing_with_scrlayer-scrpage). I cannot give a solution for `titleps`, you would have to ask @Bernard about it.

Comment: Yes if it can solve my problem why not you can post the code with scelayer-scrpage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example using package `scrlayer-scrpage`. Chapter `Alpaca` is equivalent to your Introduction chapter and just shows the title in the header (it isn't numbered). Numbered chapters have the word Chapter and the respective number in the header, alalong with the title.

If you decide not to have the header on the page a chapter starts, remove the asterisk from `ihead`.

I would suggest to make the top and bottom margins a bit bigger.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{unnumberedtotoc}%https://github.com/johannesbottcher/unnumberedtotoc/
\usepackage[automark,
plainheadsepline,
headsepline,
plainfootsepline,
footsepline,
markcase=ignoreupper]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead*{\leftmark}
\cfoot*{\pagemark}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\scshape}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[a4paper,right=20mm,left=25mm,top=20mm, bottom=20mm,%
head=14.5pt,%<- new
]{geometry}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{20pt}
\titleformat{\paragraph}
{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\addchap{Alpaca}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\chapter{state of art}
\lipsum
\chapter{theory}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: I am curious why you are using `titlesec` in the first place? The result seems to be the same to the default?

Comment: How can I add the unnumberedtotoc package in MiKTex

Comment: @twimo https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-or-cls-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-te or https://github.com/johannesbottcher/unnumberedtotoc/#downloading-this-package

Comment: But to be honest, the package is not directly related to the problem, but solves the follow up problem you would have had.

Comment: I still have problems in installing the package

Comment: @twimo Put it in the same folder your project is in.

Comment: @twimo glad to hear.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74707/discussion-between-twimo-and-johannes-b).